# How to configure a Bluetooth keyboard to open and close a specific app?

Tags: keyboard

I want to convert my Bluetooth keyboard to some sort of control panel for my car, to open maps etc on keypress. So that I don't need to use the touchscreen while driving.

Is that possible?

Comment: Looks like some old phones with integrated physical keyboard had this functionality:https://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/smartphones/droid/quick-launch-feature-for-android-phone-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your keyboard have media buttons by any chance? If so you can use something like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_AU) or [Automate (Free)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) to programatically set actions. I happen to have Automate on my phone and just checked you can use media buttons as a trigger e.g. pause, play, next, previous, eject etc. Then you can hook this up to start apps and voice searches easily - the interface is pretty straightforward if you haven't used one of these apps before.

If your keyboard doesn't have media buttons a generic bluetooth remote of some sort could work (try ebay/aliexpress etc.)

Quick google search says Tasker [can't capture generic keypresses](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/Mq-QrFL7tIM) but that might've changed since 2015.

Comment: Awesome! I have some media buttons on it, great!